# ASP.NET MVC 4 bundles, paths, and the leading slash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

First I define a bundle:

```
var bootstrapBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/css/styles").Include(
                                 "~/assets/css/bootstrap.css");
```

And then, in my layout file:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css/styles")
```

which renders to:

```
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My problem is that I'm sharing my assets between 2 projects and I need the following:

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

(note the absense of leading spash in the stylesheet path)

Any way I can achieve that while still referencing the bundle? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried "var bootstrapBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/css/styles").Include(
                                 "~assets/css/bootstrap.css");"?

Comment: @Landeeyo - I only get server error with this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is a good idea to share the assests in development, but in production however there are buildin features to use so that you can share the known assets like bootstrap.css.

example:

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

to test it make sure debug="false" in web.config.

source
http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2014/07/cdn-in-aspnet-mvc-bundling.html

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. I've put "bootstrap.css" only as an example - there can be any stylesheet.

Comment: this is an example for jquery from cdn server but "there can be any stylesheet"